# QGIS pgRoutingLayer database connection missing on localhost

Tags: qgis, postgresql, qgis-plugins, pgrouting

Copied the network tables to localhost. Now pgRoutingLayer will not show the connection under "Database" anymore. What am I missing? The username and password is saved in QGIS under the localhost connection, so it's not that.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database connection established. Turned out the pg Routing extension was not properly run in pgAdmin 4 (the database). Instead of using the GUI,

Database --> Create --> Extension

the extension had to be run in the following SQL query format:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pgrouting; 
SELECT pgr_version();
```